# Want to sanitize a word in a view, how to include the SanitizeHelper module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, ruby-on-rails-4, special-characters, html-sanitizing

I have words like the following: "torbjörn".

I want to replace special characters like the 6th letter "ö" with the latin equivalant, i.e. "o".

I assume [the module `SanitizeHelper`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html) will do this for me, but I don't understand how and where to include it.

I just need this for one view, so if it's favorable to not include it for the whole app, I would like to have that taken in mind as well.

Comment: usually rails is able to go with umlaut and also with national characters. the user interface is no problem. where do you want the replacement?

Comment: I'm converting some words to class selectors, so I'd rather not have special characters...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`transliterate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-transliterate):

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector::transliterate "torbjörn" # => "torbjorn"
```

Comment: can we do the reverse of that too

Comment: No, that's impossible unless you store the original value somewhere